# object of type closure is not subsettable yet returns result

Tags: r

I have seen multiple posts about this topic, and in every case I have seen the error was caused by trying to subset something that was not subsettable. Yet when I run this code every part of it is subsettable. Why is this happening?

```
df<-NULL
df$col1<-c(1,2,3)
df$extraversion<-c(4,3,5)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
lm(df[,1]~df$extraversion) #works perfectly
lm(paste0("df[,1]~df$extraversion")) #Error in df[, 1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
df[,1] #returns: [1] 1 2 3
df$extraversion #returns: [1] 4 3 5
```

Comment: Thanks.  Glad I could help.

Comment: `df` is the name of an R function which is why you got the error you did.. You should learn not to use names of functions for data arguments. R function names include `data`, `dt`, `,rf`, `new`, and `matrix`. Use short descriptive names. You should also learn to pass a dataframe to the data argument of `lm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `as.formula()`. Try:

```
lm(as.formula(paste0("df[,1]~df$extraversion")))
```